# Tying angular files together

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am new to Angular and have done some tutorials but am now getting to working on my own project, using John Popa style guide.

My question is: if you have one component per file, how do you tie it together? Do I need to call the script src of every individual file in the HTML?

Comment: Every component in angular (angular 2 and above) is an exportable class. Script tags are a thing of the past. You should absolutely take the Tour of Heroes tutorial on angular.io

Comment: Thanks! I plan on it after I sort out what I'm doing on this project. I'm in a bit too deep now to switch frameworks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will tie views (html) and viewmodels (js code) together thru the routing

after adding the reference to your JS File in index page  section  ( )

it all depends on what router are you using, there is a quick sample

```
$routeProvider
        .when("/routename", {
            templateUrl: "path/to/yourt/htmlfile.html",
            controller: 'controlerNameDeclared in your Controller'
        })
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I reference app.module.js, and app.config.js and controller.js in the index.html?

Comment: Correct, all your controllers, directives, services, etc, any .js file

Comment: And at some point later I assume they will all combine to one file and be minified, at which point I only need to script tag one file?

Comment: correct, don't forget to declare your dependencies correctly `someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter)` or your minifier will mess al your code

Comment: keep in mind that what is being discussed above is angular 1 (referred to as  angularjs) and not angular 2/4 (referred to as angular). In angular (angular 2/4) there is no concept of controllers anymore, just classes. I suggest that unless you have a requirement of using angular 1, go ahead and start learning angular 2/4. Angular 2 and Angular 4 are the same thing minus some new items on angular 4. Version 3 was skipped entirely (which is why you have that jump from 2 to 4).